# Persistent Cache to store in Java

Tags: java, caching, persistence

I have to store data in hashmap in a cache which is persistent. I see a lot of in-memory cache which I will lose data if there is a system crash. 
I think a persistent cache is what I am looking at. How can I solve this problem of being able to use a persistent cache.

So I think mapdb is used for this purpose. 
Is a file based persistence slower than a database?

Comment: Have you ever heard of databases?

Comment: I dont want to use databases. They take a lot of time. Huge performance degradation.

Comment: But you think a file-based cache will be efficient??

Comment: "file based cache" => that's called a database. Most likely if you implement a "file based cache" yourself, it will be less efficient than a databas.

Comment: "immutable" != never can change the data. It means that instead of modifying tha actual data, you make a copy, modify the copy, and then save the copy as a new key while deleting the old key.

Comment: If you want something that is persistent, your best bet is a database. They are (often) slower than a in-memory solution, but that's because they offer you a lot more. You can do a combination: use in-memory cache for speed but write all updates to a database (eg a noSQL) so you can recover them when your system crashes.

Comment: I dont want to deal with the whole issue of creating database, schema, primary key and stuff like that. I just want a hashmap which is persistent.

Comment: Is a file based persistent system slower than database?

Comment: "Is a file based persistent system slower than database?" => a database is *by definition* a file-based persistent system. Database designers spend lots of time optimising their software, so your best bet is to use what's already built rather than attempting to write your own solution. If you use a noSQL database such as MongoDB (as suggested by @SOlsson), you do not have to deal with creating a schema at all. In fact, MongoDB behaves like a massive hashmap. It caches a significant chunk of data in memory, so it will likely be *better* than whatever purely file-based system you write.